# NodeJS and Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp, webpack

I want to create app with nodeJS and angular2 as client side framework. For example I have routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('about');
});
app.get('/dash', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'path-to-angular2-index-file.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

However Angular2 tutorial doesn't covered such and agular-cli comes with their own method: [Generating and serving an Angular2 project via a development server](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server)

I have following folder structure:

```
NodeJSWebsite
--node_modules
--public
--|--img
--|--css
--|--js
--|--templates
----|--home.hbs
----|--about.hbs
--server.js
--package.json
```

Is there a good & simple way to compile/build angular2 application and render html file so I am able to use with my route?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great solution coming. But it's currently in alpha, you can still use it however. It's called [AngularUniversal](https://universal.angular.io/).

There official starter built with express is available on github [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use this seed project- http://matthiasschuetz.com/angular2-seed/

This is a basic Angular 2 TypeScript starter project which covers-

- a routing concept (separate route configuration file)
- login and dashboard view components (authorized/public routes)
- error page handling
- a directive (form inputs)
- a service (authorization)
- a pipe (determine the active route)
- uses es6-shim, Reflect, Rx.js and Zone.js

It relies on TypeScript, SystemJS, Gulp and Sass.

Source code link - https://github.com/matthias-schuetz/angular2-seed

---

You can also take a look at Angular2 Webpack Starter.

Details are available here - https://angularclass.github.io/angular2-webpack-starter/

Source code is available here - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter